# jquery ui-dialog can't see html text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i got a ui-dialog which i need to set its content message 
but i can't seem to see the text 
my function is as follows

```
function showSuccessMessage(user,reg)
{
    var msg;
    if (reg == true)
         msg = "User "+user.toString() +" Successfully Registered";
    else
         msg = "User " + user.toString() + " Successfully Edited";
    $("#box").dialog({
          title:"User Registration",         
          html:msg,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
                 Ok: function () {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                        var s = "../Pages/main.aspx";                
                        window.location = s;
                     }
           }
     });
```

} // end function

any idea what i'm setting wrong all the other properties accept html work 
is html even  the content text attribute ? i couldn't come across any source verifying this

thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't know what an XSS hole is

maybe your calling me an XSS hole :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting  By putting user-controlled data in the HTML, you allow users to inject HTML or Javascript.

Comment: o'k ill check it out 
thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.dialog` doesn't have an `html` parameter.

You should set the text of the element directly:

```
$('#box').text(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
function showSuccessMessage(user,reg)
{
    var msg;
    if (reg == true)
         $('#box').html("User "+user.toString() +" Successfully Registered");
    else
         $('#box').html("User " + user.toString() + " Successfully Edited");
    $("#box").dialog({
          title:"User Registration",         

          modal: true,
          buttons: {
                 Ok: function () {
                      $(this).dialog("close");
                        var s = "../Pages/main.aspx";                
                        window.location = s;
                     }
           }
     });
}
```

Comment: i just found an answer like a minute ago  which says the same
:)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336915/jquery-ui-dialog-how-to-change-text-once-the-dialog-is-opened